# Read UTF-8 CSV file into string with special characters inside fails

Tags: java, csv, utf-8, download

I wrote an export script for my magento shop. The script exports my products correctly into an UTF-8 CSV file. No problems with special characters here.

Now I want my Java application to read my file (e.g. http://www.foo.com/bar.csv) and store the content in a string.

This is my Java code:

```
        URL urlObj = new URL(url);
        URLConnection urlConnection = urlObj.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }

        String outputString = stringBuilder.toString();
```

My output look like this:

ZubehÃÂ¶r instead of Zubehör

I already tried this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

And all variations ;)

Anyone with an idea?

Cheers

Comment: How you know it? Do you print it to console or use debugger to watch value?

Comment: try this: **new String(line, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));**

Comment: I used the debugger to watch the values.
Later I store the value in my database later (DB is completely on UTF-8 as well).

Comment: @Christian  most likely your db is not UTF-8  ( for example mysql is kinda tricky to set it to utf-8 encoding) . to ensure that its the case or not, try to write the string into a file so u can see it. before gettin into the DB

Comment: @nafas: The special character problem is BEFORE the DB insert. Right after downloading the CSV content, there are problems with the special characters.

Comment: @Christian did you try this : **stringBuilder.append(new String(line, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));**?

Comment: @nafas: I tried it right now: "no suitable constructor found for String(java.lang.String,java.nio.charset.Charset)"

Comment: @Christian I guess you are using java 1.6. you can try this: `new String(line.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"))`

Comment: @nafas Thanks for your help, but it didn't work. Still the same problem with the special chars...